# How do I get the Input from ActiveX InputBox in Excel to be in my VBA code?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make a user data entry sheet in Excel so it can filter out the database from the other worksheet, however, I don't know how to take the data that I get from this entry sheet to be use and saved in my VBA code.

Here's my data entry sheet:

[image]

What I'm trying to do is to replace the Pop-up InputBox from this code and replace the input from the data entry sheet. This is the previous code:

```
Sub InputFilter()

    Dim strInput As String
    Dim strInput1 As String
    Dim strInput2 As String

        ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
        strInput = InputBox("Enter your value to filter WPP")
        'Selection.AutoFilter
        ActiveSheet.Range("$A$4:$BL$351").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:=strInput 'User Input for desired WPP

        strInput1 = InputBox("Enter your Product Category")
        'Selection.AutoFilter
        ActiveSheet.Range("$A$4:$BL$351").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=strInput1 'User Input for Product Category

....
```

And turn it into something like this, but It keeps throwing 438 error and the data from the entry sheet doesn't want to replace the strInput

```
Sub test()

ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data Domestic").strInput = ActiveSheet("Sheet").txtWPP.Value
ActiveSheet("Raw Data Domestic").Range("$A$4:$BL$351").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:=strInput


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ActiveSheet.Range("$A$4:$BL$351").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=strInput` requires a string to be assigned to the `Criteria1` property. It doesn't matter where this string comes from. Any of the following will do and more examples could be given.

```
strInput = InputBox("Enter your value to filter WPP")
or
strInPut = ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 1).value
or
strInput = ActiveSheet.txtWPP.Value
```

Just remember that `ActiveSheet` specifies the active sheet, whatever its name. `ActiveSheet("Sheet")` is, therefore an impossibility. It's either just `ActiveSheet` or `Worksheets("Sheet")`.